# Configuring xUnit for CUnit in Hudson CI

Tags: hudson, xunit, cunit

I want to use Hudson CI for my c-project, which also uses CUnit. However I've also come to understand that there is currently no plugin that supports CUnit. So I read [on the internets](http://www.van-porten.de/2009/05/cunit-tests-in-hudson/) that this might be possible using the xUnit plugin by translating between CUnit and JUnit, but using the supplied file yields an error.

```
[xUnit] [ERROR] - The plugin hasn't been performed correctly: Conversion error Error to convert the input XML document
```

So my question is; has anyone successfully run CUnit tests in hudson. And, in that case, how?

Comment: What version of Hudson & xUnit are you using?

Comment: Ah, I'm running Hudson 1.386 and xUnit 1.12

Comment: If you can, try comparing your resulting xml file with a JUnit xml file. Also make sure your xml file is valid @http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there were some syntax errors in the xslt-file provided in the link. After correcting this and some identifiers it worked out well.

Answer (score 1):

@Nubsis: Did you by any chance copy & paste from the listing? The downloadable file seems to work just fine. 
If you found errors in it let me know so I can fix them and put an updated version on my blog so others don't run into the same problems you had.

Comment: Yes, the errors seems to have been in the listing. The downloaded file seems to work fine, so it seems that it was indeed the highlighting that broke it.